# Classification report

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, classification

I have a simple question about classification reports and validation generator in keras.

In my case each number in valid_generator.classes corresponds to an artist. But how do i know which number each artist has?

```py
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

valid_generator.reset()

valid_generator = _val_generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = test_info, 
    directory = test_folder, x_col = "filename", 
    y_col = "artist", seed = 42,
    batch_size = 1, shuffle = False, 
    class_mode="sparse", target_size = IMAGE_SIZE)

Y_pred = model.predict(valid_generator)
y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)

print(classification_report(valid_generator.classes, y_pred))
```

Output:

```py
     precision    recall  f1-score   support
0       0.43      0.45      0.44        44
1       0.80      0.40      0.53        10
2       0.50      0.35      0.41        20
3       0.33      0.24      0.28        21
4       0.79      0.50      0.61        22
5       0.56      0.58      0.57        77
6       0.62      0.38      0.47        21

etc..
```

Comment: Converting the target random variable into a sparse categorical random variable is a part of preprocessing. Can you please post the code from there?

Comment: @kate-melnykova I think i maybe can make a hacky solution to this, looping through the test_info "artist" column and assigning a number to each artist because the generator have shuffle=False, this should work i think. If i am not able to solve it that way i will post the code you suggested.